# How do I set focus to an element outside the current frame?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a simple userform for entering data into a macro:

[image]

Everything works fine, except for one thing - I want the commandbuttons at the bottom to get focus, after the textboxes are populated from a different form which pops up when either textbox is clicked.

Stepping through the code this does indeed happen, but somehow focus is returned to the textbox before the code ends.

Googling about a bit, it seems that the issue may be that there is a frame around the textboxes, but I can't find any way to actually solve the problem.

The code for the two textboxes is next to similar, and looks like this:

```
Private Sub tbxTil_Enter()
  DATA_TO_CALENDAR = Me.tbxTil.Value
  DatePickerForm.Show
  Me.tbxTil.Value = Format(DATA_FROM_CALENDAR, "dd.mmm. yyyy")
  If Me.cmdOk.Enabled Then
    Me.cmdOk.SetFocus
  Else
    Me.cmdAvbryt.SetFocus
  End If
End Sub
```

Assuming the problem is what I believe it is, is there any way to set the focus to an element outside the frame you are currently in? If not, what is the actual issue with my code?

Comment: It's timing. The Enter event occurs before your control actually gets the focus. So setting the focus elsewhere works, but then focus is automatically returned to the textbox.

Comment: @rory It works in userforms without frames though? What makes this UF different?

Comment: Frames are containers and events like Enter and Exit are actually inherited from the container. Why do you need frames anyway - you could just use labels to simulate them without the side effects.

Comment: @rory It looks prettier, and allows for easy grouping of controls inside it :P There is actually no easy way to set the focus to something outside the frame, if I choose to use those in a form?

Comment: But you don't need them here. It's very difficult from events that are themselves triggered by a change in focus.

Comment: Well, the question isn't really about whether or not I need them. Furthermore there may be another time when I, or someone else, do need them, so an answer to whether or not this problem can be handled by VBA would be nice. Following your comments regarding timing, I tried using a few other ones, e.g. `textbox_change` but none of those worked either. I assume that means everything inside the frame inherits their events from the frame? @rory

Comment: No. A simple change event should have no problem setting the focus elsewhere.

Comment: @Rory Nevertheless it fails, and I am having little luck with figuring out why =/ Oh, well, gonna go with no frames for now and try to figure out what is going on when I have more time on hand.

Comment: It works just fine here - I suspect you have something else interfering.

Comment: @rory Yeah, my guess is that after the enter-event has caused the change-event to fire, control is handed back to the enter-event, which brings us back to the original problem. Hmm, I wonder, could raising a custom error prevent this from happening?

Comment: You coud avoid the whole issue by having a little button next to each textbox to launch your calendar control.